# How do I link an external website to an imported React src image?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using a Gatsby starter theme that uses react and I imported a local image at the top of the code and call it in different in a section of the page using an img src tag. The image shows up perfectly but I want it to go to another website when I click it.

Is it possible to have this image link to an external website?

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import pic03 from '../images/pic03.png'




<article id="guides" className={`${this.props.article === 'about' ? 'active' :
 ''} ${this.props.articleTimeout ? 'timeout' : ''}`} style={{display:'none'}}>

   <h2 className="major">Guides</h2>
   <span className="image main"><img src={pic03} alt="" /></span>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur et adipiscing elit. Praesent eleifend dignissim arcu, at eleifend sapien imperdiet ac. </p>
   {close}
 </article>
```

Comment: look into how anchor tags work

Answer (score 1):

In Gatsby you can use the Link tag for internal linking, but for external you can surround the image with an `<a>` tag and use a href to direct where ever you want. Like so: `<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src={pic03} alt="" /></a>`

You can even set a target attribute to determine if you want to open in a new tab or not like so:`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src={pic03} alt="" /></a>`

Comment: Thank you, this did it!